# How to make login Screen which will redirect different users to different screens?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I am Trying to make lo-gin Screen which will redirect different users to different screens.
i have a database table.
The fields are.
sql table Design

```
username Varchar(50)
password Varchar(50)
Designation Text
IsAdmin bit
```

now i have two text fields respectively with a login button

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Login1.UserName;
        string password = Login1.Password;
        string CurrentName;

        string s;
        s = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ovmsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
        con.Open();
        string sqlUserName;

        //FOR NORMAL USERS

    if(username != null)
            {


            sqlUserName = "SELECT username,password FROM tblLogin WHERE username ='" + username + "' AND password ='" + password + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName, con);


            CurrentName = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (CurrentName != null)
            {
                Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
                Session.Timeout = 1;
                Response.Redirect("start.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["UserAuthentication"] = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show Drivers a different page after login and the Admin a Different page(Admin Panel).

I have two Queries i just want to make admin pannel login, user login screen and driver login screen through a single FORM.

```
like :
Query for driver

SELECT     username, password, Designation
FROM         dbo.tblLogin
WHERE     (Designation LIKE 'driver')

and for Admin Login

SELECT     username, password, IsAdmin
FROM         dbo.tblLogin
WHERE     (IsAdmin = 1)
```

Comment: fyi: You may want to meet [Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) on your own terms. Cleartext passwords in the database? Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two roles one for Admin and another for drivers.

In your login code, check the role the user belongs to and redirect based on that.

if (Roles.IsUserInRole(userName,"Admin"))
{
     return ReirectToAction("", "AdminHomepage");
}
else
{
     return ReirectToAction("", "DriversHomepage");
}

Comment: what about the rest of the users?

Comment: seems that i have to make a role for every user, is that what you are saying. Like i have accountant, teacher, Admin officer.......etc

Comment: Create roles for different kind of users you can have on the application. take for example drivers and admin are two different roles. if i have 30 drivers, i will add them all in the role drivers.